# How to query MongoDB with "LIKE" and "NOT LIKE"?

Tags: php, mongodb

I've an array like this

```
array(
  'ts' : 123456789,
  'nm' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
)
...
array(
  'ts' : 122345678,
  'nm' : 'Nulla lorem purus, pretium porttitor ultricies sit amet, rutrum sollicitudin risus.'
)
```

How to find elements who contains '*amet*' AND not contains '*ipsum*' in 'nm'?
And how to find elements who contais both '*amet*' and '*ipsum*' ?

Comment: Don't write "solved" in your question. Post an answer.

Comment: Solution has been posted below

Comment: Thanks. And if it's the one you went with you'd usually self-accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION**

```
array(
  'nm' => array(
    '$all' => array(new MongoRegex('/amet/'), ...),
    '$nin' => array(new MongoRegex('/ipsum/'), ...)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing Mongo has to `LIKE` is regexes:

```
db.my_collection.find({nm: /amet/})
```

but I don't think you can do what you ask for unless you can write a single regex that captures both the contains and not-contains part of your query.

That said, just as with `LIKE`, Mongo's regex queries are not performant. If you need full text search you should look to something like Solr, or a database that has full text indexes built in.